# displaying data on php

Tags: php, mysql

>

```
</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "engine");
if ($conn-> connect_error) {

    die("connection files:" . $conn-> connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT location , brand, model, origin, mfgdate from engines ";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>". 
        $row["location"] . "</td<td>" . 
        $row["brand"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["model"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["origin"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["mfgdate"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "0 result";
}
$conn->close();
?>



</table>
```

[when code is execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcJ0h.png)

actually "test"=location test1=brand test2=model test3= origin and date  enter is =mfgdate

please help me to arrange table

Comment: Just fix missing `>` in this line: `$row["location"] . "</td><td>" . `

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I am surprised that it does not show that error with colo(u)r

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$row["location"] . "</td<td>"
```

use

```
$row["location"] . "</td><td>"
```

(missing ending `>` in the tag).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem related a syntax error.

You are missing a > closing a td.

```
    </tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "engine");
if ($conn-> connect_error) {

    die("connection files:" . $conn-> connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT location , brand, model, origin, mfgdate from engines ";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>". 
        $row["location"] . "</td><td>" . 
        $row["brand"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["model"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["origin"] . "</td><td>". 
        $row["mfgdate"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "0 result";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
```

However it is a best practice to generate the data in php and sent to client server and then place the values into the table.